# Meteor.js / spacebars - Why does data context change when calling template with arguments/variables?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

I have a child template, label:

```
<template name="label">{{name}}</template>
```

I include in a parent template (the data context of which defines `name`) like so:

**A:** `<template name="parent">{{> label}}</template>`

I want to set, e.g., the width, from the parent. To do so I provide it with an argument for width:

**B:** `<template name="parent">{{> label width="100%"}}</template>`

In **B**, the label template loses the data context of the parent and {{name}} is now undefined. In **A**, it maintains the data context and works fine. Why?

What can I do to fix this, other than this undesirable solution:

**This works, but I don't want to do this:**

```
<template name="parent">{{> label data=this width="100%"}}</template>
<template name="label">{{data.name}}</template>
```

Answer (score 4):

The argument passed to a template *is* the data context. If you don't pass an argument, the data context defaults to `this`, the current data context of the caller. Also, the `label` template won't use the width passed to it if you don't use it yourself. Fixed code:

```
<template name="parent">{{> label name=name width="100%"}}</template>
<template name="label"><span width={{width}}>{{data.name}}</span></template>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I guess that makes sense and what I am asking for is not possible to do easily. 

Also, I believe {{width}} in your example should be in quotes (also note that the data context doesn't need to be accessed from the template -- it can also be accessed from javascript).